# running make on 'alsa.mk' causes make to read every file in directory tree

Tags: makefile, debian

I'm fairly experienced with C/C++/C# in the Windows environment, but a complete noob wrt Linux and makefiles.  I want to contribute to the XCSoar development project (https://github.com/XCSoar), so I'm working my way through a complex makefile project, where 'secondary' (*.mk) files are defined for every module (.cpp) file.  The secondary make files are 'Include'd at the start of the main makefile ('Makefile').  I use vscode to look at some of the secondary .mk files, and decided to try running 'make' in debug (-d) mode on a random (home/XCSoar/build/alsa.mk) secondary .mk file

Here's the file :

```
ifeq ($(TARGET),ANDROID)
# Using ALSA directly makes no sense on Android
ENABLE_ALSA = n
else ifeq ($(ENABLE_SDL),y)
# If SDL is being used, we do not use ALSA directly
# unless it is explicitly activated
ENABLE_ALSA ?= n
else ifeq ($(TARGET_IS_LINUX),y)
# Enable ALSA for Linux by default
ENABLE_ALSA ?= y
else
# ALSA must be activated explicitly on all other platforms
ENABLE_ALSA ?= n
endif

ifeq ($(ENABLE_ALSA),y)

$(eval $(call pkg-config-library,ALSA,alsa))
ALSA_CPPFLAGS += -DENABLE_ALSA

endif

frank@M6700:~/7.42_tst/XCSoar$ make -d alsa.mk | less
```

and this is what I got:

```
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile'...
Reading makefile 'build/local-config.mk' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'build/make.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'build/thunk.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'build/bool.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'build/string.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'build/dirs.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'build/verbose.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'build/util.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
```

.
.
.

```
Reading makefile 'output/UNIX/dbg/src/Computer/Events.d' (search path) (no ~ 

expansion)...
Reading makefile 'output/UNIX/dbg/src/Computer/FlyingComputer.d' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'output/UNIX/dbg/src/Computer/GlideComputerAirData.d' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'output/UNIX/dbg/src/Computer/GlideComputerBlackboard.d' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'output/UNIX/dbg/src/Computer/GlideComputer.d' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'output/UNIX/dbg/src/Computer/GlideComputerInterface.d' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'output/UNIX/dbg/src/Computer/GlideRatioCalculator.d' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'output/UNIX/dbg/src/Computer/GlideRatioComputer.d' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
```

...

```
Considering target file 'build/make.mk'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'build/make.mk'.
  No implicit rule found for 'build/make.mk'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'build/make.mk'.
 No need to remake target 'build/make.mk'.
 Pruning file 'build/local-config.mk'.
 Considering target file 'Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for 'Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'Makefile'.
 No need to remake target 'Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'alsa.mk'.
 File 'alsa.mk' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'alsa.mk'.
 No implicit rule found for 'alsa.mk'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'alsa.mk'.
Must remake target 'alsa.mk'.
```

AFAICT, 'make' considered *every file* in the entire home/build directory tree - is this normal?

TIA,

Frank

Answer (score 0):

> AFAICT, 'make' considered *every file* in the entire home/build directory tree - is this normal?

**TL;DR:** that does not appear to be what `make` is doing, but yes, what it *is* doing appears to be normal under the circumstances.

As far as I can tell (and what I would expect) is that `make` is reading the makefile and all files directly or indirectly `include`d in it.  I see no reason to think that it read source files, or headers, or existing binaries, object files, or local libraries, or source-control files, or documentation files, *etc*..  It did read a bunch of files, but surely nowhere near *all* of them.  And that it read a lot of files is partially a function of the somewhat unusual way that this particular package's build system is designed.

But let's take a step back. You seem to have a couple of serious misunderstandings about `make`:

1. The idea of "running make on 'alsa.mk'" doesn't make much sense on its face. `make`'s is not a scripting language, **makefiles are not scripts**, and `make` rules are not functions.  Makefiles are a bit like reference manuals.  When `make` wants to build a particular file, it consults the makefile that it is presently using (if any) to figure out how to perform that build, including what other files it might need to build or update first, how to build *them*, *etc*..  As a convenience, `make` does have a sense of a default target that it will attempt to build if you don't otherwise specify one, but most makefiles inform `make` how to build multiple different things, and usually not all of them are considered for building during any particular `make` run.
2. Make's `include` effects the equivalent of a textual interpolation, much like the C preprocessor's `#include`.  It follows, then, that **makefile fragments designed to be used by inclusion in a higher-level makefile generally do not stand alone**.  Indeed, even some full-fledged makefiles in hierarchical (recursive) `make` build systems do not stand fully on their own.  The particular file you present is very much in this vein: it does not provide any build rules at all -- it just sets some variables that will be used in one or more build rules defined somewhere else.
3. The particular command you issued, **"`make -d alsa.mk`", does not instruct `make` to use `alsa.mk` to build something**.  Rather, it instructs `make` to ensure that file `alsa.mk` itself is up to date, using the default makefile for instructions.  This is why `make` read the default makefile and all the files directly or indirectly `include`d into it.

   If you want to ask `make` to use a makefile that you specify instead of one of its defaults, then `make`'s `-f` option serves that purpose.  For example, `make -d -f alsa.mk`.  But again, that particular file is not a standalone makefile.  I think you will be disappointed by the result of that command.

If you want to learn how to create `make`-based build systems then great! But I urge you to start with something much simpler.  `make` has been around for a long time, and there is a variety of good tutorials out there.  If you're the manual-reading type (I am) then you could even consider reading through the first few chapters of [the GNU `make` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html).  This version of `make` does provide a fair number of extensions beyond the POSIX specifications for `make`, so you may need to maintain some awareness of portability issues, but by my estimation, these days it is easily the most popular and widespread `make`, which leaves those issues a bit pale.

But if you just want to contribute to a project that uses a `make`-based build system, then you may not really need any of that, at least not at first.  There are a lot of things you can do for a mature project that will not require you to modify its build system.